# Any algebraic function that can be expanded as infinite series with unbounded positive integral coefficients?

Tags: power-series, examples-counterexamples

Cound one give examples of irrational algebraic function that can be expanded as infinite series with unbounded positive integral coefficients, like:

$$f(x)=\sum_0^{\infty}a_i x^i,\qquad a_i\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$$

I post the question for interest, since the first time it has not been clearly expressed, I have updated the question.

Comment: $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0} nx^n$ for $|x|<1$

Comment: For what purpose do you want such examples? And what do you mean by an "algebraic function"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4x}}{2x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty C_n x^n$$
where $C_n$ are the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

There are many other examples in the OEIS.

Comment: thank you for your answer